# While posting link on company's Facebook page, the photos don't come up

Tags: facebook-page

I am not sure why this is happening. But, When i try to post ***Link Omitted*** on the company's facebook page, the thumbnails aren't loaded by the facebook. Whereas if I try to post some earlier link from my website, like ***Link Omitted***, all the pics from that page are loaded.

Can someone tell why this happens...Also, sometimes, facebook doesn't load all the images from page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rely on how Facebook scrapping your page content which isn't a best way to achieve what you want. The reason you see image for older links is probably caching.

To ensure you have images with posting your content on Facebook you should add `og:image` OpenGraph meta tags.

For more info on this read [OpenGraph documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and use [Facebook Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check if you have any issues with scrapping and/or all details scrapped correctly.

Comment: So, if I use Open Graph protocol <meta> tags on my product pages and then paste the link on my Facebook page, things will get fine ?....Actually, using a like button will post it to my profile and not the company's page....And yes thanks for the info as it's more than helpful

Comment: thanks mate....your idea for adding OG meta-tags has worked wonders...I tested on a trial page and it works awesome